# Fixed Flex-basis does not expand with content in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I searched a lot for an answer, but I did not find any reported issue to this specific scenario. I found this one, but it's not quite the same: [flex-basis doesn't account for box-sizing:border-box](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box).

The scenario:

A container that have three inner containers, right, middle and left. Right and left occupy each 50% of the available width space (flex-basis:50%) after the middle container is calculated (flex-shrink:0).

Expected behavior:

In Chrome, when the content of the left container is wider than the calculated flex-basis width, the left container will expand to accommodate its content, and the right container will shrink.

Problem:

In Internet Explorer 11, the left container remain with the calculated flex-basis width, and the content overflows.

https://jsfiddle.net/mqxwra1d/5/

Thank in advance for your attention.

HTML

```
<div id=container>
    <div id=left>
    <div class=content></div>
    <div class=content></div>
    <div class=content></div>
  </div>
  <div id=middle>middle</div>
  <div id=right>right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
  display:flex;
  width: 280px;
}
#left,#right{
  display:flex;
  flex-basis:50%;
  flex-shrink:1;
  background:yellow;
}
#middle{
  display:flex;
  flex-shrink:0;
  background:cyan;
}
.content{
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  min-width:50px;
  margin:1px;
  background:red;  
}
```

Comment: What is the desired outcome?  Would you prefer the `#left` container to expand as necessary or do you want it absolutely constrained to `50%`?  If you want IE to display it similar to how Chrome displays it, you'll need to add `flex-basis:auto` to `#left`.  If you want Chrome to display it the way IE does, you'll need to add `max-width:50%` to `#left`.

Comment: Thank you for your input Joseph! I want the Chrome behavior, so the `#left` container to expand as necessary. I cannot add `flex-basis:auto` as I need the `#middle` to stay in the center whenever possible.

Comment: I'd like to add that the width of `#content` is variable, can be less then 100% of its parent, but the parent should have `flex-basis:50%` to keep the `#middle` in the middle.